# iPhone X / 8 / 8 Plus CSS media queries

Tags: css, media-queries, iphone-x, iphone-8, iphone-8-plus

What are the CSS media queries corresponding to Apple's new devices ? I need to set the `body`'s `background-color` to change the X's safe area background color.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

## iPhone X

```
@media only screen 
    and (device-width : 375px) 
    and (device-height : 812px) 
    and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 3) { }
```

---

## iPhone 8

```
@media only screen 
    and (device-width : 375px) 
    and (device-height : 667px) 
    and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 2) { }
```

---

## iPhone 8 Plus

```
@media only screen 
    and (device-width : 414px) 
    and (device-height : 736px) 
    and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 3) { }
```

iPhone 6+/6s+/7+/8+ share the same sizes, while the iPhone 7/8 also do.

---

Looking for a specific orientation ?

**Portrait**

Add the following rule:

```
    and (orientation : portrait)
```

**Landscape**

Add the following rule:

```
    and (orientation : landscape)
```

References:

- https://webkit.org/blog/7929/designing-websites-for-iphone-x/
- https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/
- https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/iphone-x/
- https://mydevice.io/devices/
- http://viewportsizes.com/mine/

Comment: My iphone 8+ with iOS 12 gets hit by the iPhone X query

Comment: http://viewportsizes.com/mine/ reports 320 x 450 for iPhone 8. Also reports: `Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1`.

Comment: iPhone 8 Plus media quuery doesnt work on chrome atleast.

Answer (score 91):

Here are some of the following media queries for iPhones. Here is the ref link https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions

```
        /* iphone 3 */
        @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 480px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1) { }
        
        /* iphone 4 */
        @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 480px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { }
        
        /* iphone 5 */
        @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { }
        
        /* iphone 6, 6s, 7, 8 */
        @media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { }
            
        /* iphone 6+, 6s+, 7+, 8+ */
        @media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { }
        
        /* iphone X , XS, 11 Pro, 12 Mini */
        @media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { }

        /* iphone 12, 12 Pro */
        @media only screen and (min-device-width: 390px) and (max-device-height: 844px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { }
       
        /* iphone XR, 11 */
        @media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { }
            
        /* iphone XS Max, 11 Pro Max */
        @media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { }

        /* iphone 12 Pro Max */
        @media only screen and (min-device-width: 428px) and (max-device-height: 926px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { }
```

Comment: You should add references, eg: Links to other SO answers if you copied them.

Comment: My iphone 8+ with iOS 12 gets hit by the iPhone X query

Comment: @GlennG I had updated my answer as well it's question ;)

Answer (score 21):

I noticed that the answers here are using: `device-width`, `device-height`, `min-device-width`, `min-device-height`, `max-device-width`, `max-device-height`.

**Please refrain from using them since they are deprecated**. see [MDN for reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/device-width). Instead use the regular `min-width`, `max-width` and so on. For extra assurance, you can set the min and max to the same px amount.
For example:

**iPhone X**

```
@media only screen 
    and (width : 375px) 
    and (height : 812px)
    and (orientation : portrait)  
    and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 3) { }
```

Here are a few useful links on this subject:

- https://medium.com/@hacknicity/how-ios-apps-adapt-to-the-iphone-x-screen-size-a00bd109bbb9
- https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/
- https://ivomynttinen.com/blog/ios-design-guidelines
- https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions

Comment: This is the ONLY method working, all others above, even CSS tricks are wrong, using the methods like Yash Vakeria or Josh works but they also get called on Iphone 6-7-8. 

BUT !  DO use the 812px instead of the mentionned 635px, the chrome inspector tool did not catch it as mentionned by Sam...

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the most accurate (and seamless) method of adding the padding for iPhone X/8 using env()...

```css
padding: env(safe-area-inset-top) env(safe-area-inset-right) env(safe-area-inset-bottom) env(safe-area-inset-left);
```

Here's a link describing this:

https://css-tricks.com/the-notch-and-css/

Comment: Hi Wasif, try and put ` ` around your code for nicer formatting.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is going to apply the padding on iPhone 6 as well, at least it does in the simulator. And that's undesired.

Answer (score 1):

If your page is missing `meta[@name="viewport"]` element within its DOM, then the following could be used to detect a mobile device:

```
@media only screen and (width: 980px), (hover: none) { … }
```

If you want to avoid false-positives with desktops that just magically have their viewport set to 980px like all the mobile browsers do, then a `device-width` test could also be added into the mix:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 800px) and (width: 980px), (hover: none) { … }
```

Per the list at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries, the new `hover` property would appear to be the final new way to detect that you've got yourself a mobile device that doesn't really do proper `hover`; it's only been introduced in 2018 with Firefox 64 (2018), although it's been supported since 2016 with Android Chrome 50 (2016), or even since 2014 with Chrome 38 (2014):

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/hover