# How to differentiate Iphone x media query to Iphone 6,7,8 plus?

Tags: media-queries, ionic4

I'm creating ionic 4 angular app, and written media queries for IPhones. I'm write Iphone x and Iphone 6,7,8 plus media queries but Iphone x media queries also apply on Iphone x as well as Iphone plus.how to differentiate to each other ? Below shown media queries i'm using.

```
 /* iphone 6+, 6s+, 7+, 8+ */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {}

    /* iphone X */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone X / 8 / 8 Plus CSS media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46313640/iphone-x-8-8-plus-css-media-queries)

Comment: i'm also try u r given in comment but not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because these not correct probably.

You are using `-width` on one and `-height` on the other so these media queries are not clamped exclusively.

I'm assuming the iPhone X is the biggest device but you are applying the rules from width 375px upwards... that's going to include ones that have width 414px and upwards.

It seems like this should cover all the iPhone scenarios:

```
/* ----------- iPhone 6, 6S, 7 and 8 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}

/* ----------- iPhone 6+, 7+ and 8+ ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { 

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}

/* ----------- iPhone X ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 812px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { 

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 812px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 812px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
  and (orientation: landscape) { 

}
```

You can get even more devices at:

- [Media Queries for Standard Devices | CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

### Platform Mode

Also, don't forget that Ionic lets you use the `ios` selector in the sass to restrict the devices to ios mode:

- [Overriding Mode Styles - Platform Styles - Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/platform-styles#overriding-mode-styles)

So something like:

```
.ios ion-badge {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Will restyle everything with the `mode="ios"` set, which is done by default on ios devices, although it can be manually set to other values, so only use it if that's appropriate for your project.

Comment: no not working , iphone x media query work in iphone 6,7,8 plus.

Comment: how to differentiate to both

Comment: you need to understand how css works. It cascades. You write your rules in the iphone 6,7,8,plus section first, and then you override those rules in the iphone x that you don't like.

Comment: It's cascades .Thank you. I'm using !important .it is working.